# Display Latest Post Outside of WordPress with JSON and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, blogs

I am trying to Display Latest Post Outside of WordPress with JSON and jQuery

I followed the steps which are given in this blog post. But is not working for me. Here is the [blog post](http://www.fldtrace.com/wordpress/display-latest-post-outside-of-wordpress-with-json-and-jquery) [link](http://www.fldtrace.com/wordpress/display-latest-post-outside-of-wordpress-with-json-and-jquery)

i tried [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CA8Dy/) it is not working

it shows Uncaught SyntaxError: `*Unexpected token < blog.rangde.org/api/get_recent_posts/?count=1&page=0&callback=jQuery17206551494831219316_1338883023819&_=1338883023833:3*`

Comment: When you say "outside of WordPress" do you mean on the same website or a different domain?

Answer (score 0):

The example in the link you posted was not a cross-site request.  You may be running into problems because of that.  You have to use JSONP for cross-site requests with [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Set crossDomain = true.

Also you may have better luck using CURL and [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and getting your RSS feed.